# Next Greatest Alphabet in an Array [Using Binary Search Algorithm]

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search

I am trying to solve a question on Leetcode

[Find Smallest Letter Greater Than Target](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-smallest-letter-greater-than-target/)

> Given a characters array letters that is sorted in non-decreasing order and a character target, return the smallest character in the array that is larger than target.
>
> Note that the letters wrap around.
>
> For example, if `target == 'z'` and `letters == ['a', 'b']`, the answer is 'a'.
>
> ```
> Example 1:
> Input: letters = ["c","f","j"], target = "a"
> Output: "c"
>
> Example 2:
> Input: letters = ["c","f","j"], target = "c"
> Output: "f"
>
> Example 3: 
> Input: letters = ["c","f","j"], target = "d"
> Output: "f"
> ```
>
> ### Constraints:
>
> ```
> 2 <= letters.length <= 104
> letters[i] is a lowercase English letter.
> letters is sorted in non-decreasing order.
> letters contains at least two different characters.
> target is a lowercase English letter.
> ```

My solution until now looks something like this:

```js
function nextGreatestAlphabet(letters, target){
  let left = 0; 
  let right  = letters.length - 1;
  let res = -1; 
        while(left <= right) {
            let mid = Math.floor(left + (right - left) / 2);

            if (letters[mid] == target ) { console.log(1)
                res = letters[mid];
                left = mid  + 1;
            }
            if(letters[mid] > target){  console.log(2)
                right = mid -1;
                res = letters[mid];
            }
            if(letters[mid] < target ){  console.log(3)
              left = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return res;
}

console.log(nextGreatestAlphabet(["c","f","j"],"c")); //c
```

But the correct result should be "f" as c is already present here and next greatest is f

Comment: Did you do any debugging?  What do you think is going on?  Why do you think your code is doing what it is doing?  What's your (potential) misunderstanding or bug?  Also, your code is in good enough shape that you could make it a runnable stack snippet to demonstrate/debug the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid setting `res` during the search, and certainly *not* set it when `letters[mid] == target`, as it is sure that is *not* the correct answer. Instead you should get the result after the loop has exited.

This then also means you don't need a separate case for `letters[mid] == target`, as the rest of the action is exactly what is done for `letters[mid] < target`. So you can make this a quite simple `if (letters[mid] > target) ... else ...` structure.

After the loop has exited, the `left` index points to the desired character. Then you need to deal with the boundary case where that index points beyond the array and map it to 0. This you can do with the remainder operator:

NB: I use here the name of the function as required by the LeetCode challenge:

```
function nextGreatestLetter(letters, target) {
    let left = 0; 
    let right  = letters.length - 1;

    while(left <= right) {
        let mid = Math.floor(left + (right - left) / 2);

        if(letters[mid] > target) {
            right = mid -1;
        } else {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return letters[left % letters.length];
}
```

Personally, I prefer working with `right` being the index just *after* the range that is under consideration, and for deriving `mid` you can use the `>>` operator (Array sizes are limited in this challenge, so that is a safe operation):

```
function nextGreatestLetter(letters, target) {
    let left = 0; 
    let right = letters.length;
    while (left < right) {
        let mid = (left + right) >> 1;
        if (letters[mid] > target) {
            right = mid;
        } else {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return letters[left % letters.length];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your

```
  if (letters[mid] == target ) { console.log(1)
                 res = letters[mid];
                 left = mid  + 1;
             }
```

sets the result to the target but you actually want to have the next one, so it should be sth. like

```
 res=letter[mid+1].
```

if

```
mid==letters.length - 1
```

holds then it is already the right end. then you can just put

```
res = letter[0];
```